# It can happen that $M_1 \cap M_2 =\emptyset $ but $M_1 \cup M_2$ is not a $k$-dimensional manifold. Give a counter example.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, manifolds

Let $M_1,M_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be $k$-dimensional manifolds, $ M=M_1 \cup M_2$

> It can happen that $M_1 \cap M_2 =\emptyset $ but $M$ is not a
>   $k$-dimensional manifold. Give a counter example.

So I think my example of $M_1= (0,1)\times \{0\}$, $M_2=(1,2)\times \{0\}$ is good as $M$ here doesn't sustain this condition for manifolds:

- *There exists a permutation $(i_1,\dots,i_n)$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and a mapping $g:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, continuously
  differentiable near $(x_{0,i_1},\dots,x_{0,i_n})$ such that  $$ x\in
     M \iff g(x_{i_1},\dots, x_{i_k})=(x_{i_{k+1}},\dots,x_{i_n}) \text{
     for all $x$ near $x_0$}$$*

but my friend here doesn't agree... can anyone help settle this?

**EDIT:** Can anyone give a counter-example then?

Comment: Your example is a 1-dinensional manifold.

Comment: :( can you give an example then?

Comment: Normally one uses $\bigcap$ in things like $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i\in\mathcal I} A_i$ and $\cap$ in things like $A\cap B$ and $A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$.  I edited accordingly and did some other MathJax usage improvements as well. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, I can. The problem with your example is it's still locally Euclidean. Can you think of a (simple!) space that you can decompose into two 1D manifolds? Keep in mind that while the two sets have to be disjoint, they can still be arbitrarily close to one another.

Comment: Maybe something with rational and Irrational numbers?

Comment: I believe I am a colleague of yours. The first question required that each set of the union does not contain the boundary of the other... I think we should go in that direction.

Comment: Yes I think we are, I got it though. I used M1= X axis without (0,0) and M2=Y axis